# Why does IntelliJ suggest to convert a call chain into a Sequence?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, set, code-inspection, intellij-inspections

Assume the following Kotlin example that maps the source set `src` to a destination set `dst`:

```
private val src: Set<String> = setOf("hello", "world")
private val dst: Set<Int> = src.map { it.length }.toSet()
```

This works fine. However, IntelliJ's code inspection suggests: ***Call chain on collection should be converted into 'Sequence':***

[image: Call chain on collection should be converted into 'Sequence']

Applying this suggestion results in

```
private val dst: Set<Int> = src.asSequence().map { it.length }.toSet()
```

What is the benefit of this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In this case the suggestion is suboptimal. The correct way to rewrite this code (which also doesn't result in any IntelliJ warnings) is:

```
src.mapTo(hashSetOf()) { it.length }
```

This will avoid the creation of an intermediate list that will be subsequently converted to a set; the data will be added to the resulting set right away.

Comment: Thanks, I created an issue about this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-26926.

Comment: I haven't seen the usage of `mapTo` a lot. Is it somewhere mentioned as an idiom? Especially the shown use case if a great example

Answer (score 14):

`Set.map` returns a list, which you then immediately throw away after converting it to a set. The benefit of `asSequence` is that the sequence does the conversion, presumably without a temporary list.